# get XML Namespace Elements with C#

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.ios

I having a bit of trouble parsing an xml file with a namespace
XML Format

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:fh="http://rss.flightstats.com/ns/rss/1.0">
<channel>
  <item>
    <fh:FlightHistory FlightHistoryId="271955988" DepartureDate="2012-08-16 00:30" ArrivalDate="2012-08-16 04:09" 
    </fh:FlightHistory>
  </item>
</channel>
```

I want to read `fh:FlightHistory` attributes with C# , but I didn't find any solution .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Linq-to-XML` and `Linq` itself

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"file.xml");
 XNamespace ns="http://rss.flightstats.com/ns/rss/1.0";

 var flight = doc.Descendants(ns + "FlightHistory");
 foreach (var ele in flight)
 {
  Console.WriteLine(ele.Attribute("FlightHistoryId").Value);
  }
```

OR

```
  var flight = doc.Descendants(ns + "FlightHistory")
                  .Select(ele => new 
                   {
                       FlightHistoryId=ele.Attribute("FlightHistoryId").Value,
                       DepartureDate=ele.Attribute("DepartureDate").Value,
                       ArrivalDate=ele.Attribute("ArrivalDate").Value 
                   }).FirstOrDefault();
    if (flight != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(flight.FlightHistoryId + " " + flight.DepartureDate + " " + flight.ArrivalDate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in Regular expression

```
string xmlFileString="<rss version.....</item></channel>";

Regex r=new Regex("(?<=<fh:FlightHistory).*?(?=>|</fh:FlightHistory>)",RegexOptions.Singleline);

foreach(Match m in r.Matches(xmlFileString))
Console.WriteLine(m.Value);//your required output
```