# Youtube feed parse xml c# razor

Tags: c#, api, razor, youtube, umbraco

I'm trying to parse the youtube xml feed and loop through the videos of a certain user, how do you do it? I'm using umbraco razor ( c# ).

```
@using System;
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Xml;
@using umbraco.MacroEngines;
@using System.Xml.Linq;
@inherits System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator;
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext;
@inherits DynamicNodeContext

@{
    dynamic xmlv = new DynamicXml(umbraco.library.GetXmlDocumentByUrl("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[username]/uploads"));   

    <ul>
    @foreach (var property in xmlv.BaseElement.Elements.Where(x => x.Elements("Name") == "group"))
    {
        <li>
           <p>
            @property.Title
            @property.Content
            @property.Thumbnail
           </p>
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed");
XNamespace media = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
XNamespace yt = "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007";

var items = xDoc.Descendants(media + "group")
                .Select(i => new
                {
                    Title = i.Element(media + "title").Value,
                    Content = i.Element(media + "content").Attribute("url").Value,
                    Thumbnail = i.Element(media + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value,
                    Uploaded = (DateTime)i.Element(yt + "uploaded"),
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: I notice there's another field in the youtube media:group element, <yt:uploaded>, how would you access that?

Comment: sorted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019152/get-xml-namespace-elements-with-c-sharp